# Using ajax to insert into database

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have an anchor tag which i want to use to go to a certain page but at the same time i want to use the onclick function to insert into a databse.

here's what i got so far:
html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  alert("txtHint");
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","submit.php?click="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<a onclick="showUser('test')" href="http:www.google.com">click here</a>
```

and here's the php file:

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT `clicked` FROM `links`
WHERE open = ".$_GET['link'])
or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )
$x = $row['clicked'];
$y = $x++;

$result2 = mysql_query("
UPDATE `db_name`.`links` 
SET `clicked` = $y 
WHERE `links`.`open` = '".$_GET['link']."'
")
or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_fetch_array($result2);
```

It's going to google as it should, but it isn't inserting into the database.

Any ideas?

thanks in advance,

Reece

edit- i have fixed all the errors in the php file thanks everyone, it now inserts properly when just visiting the php page with a click in the url.

BUT it still does not insert using the ajax. clearly there is something i have done wrong with the  code.

any ideas?

thanks

**edit2 solved**-

for anyone thats interested, the problem with the ajax code was this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","submit.php?click="+str,true);
```

it needed to be like this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/submit.php?click="+str,true);
```

Comment: Does your request reach the server? Does the server log any error in error_log? Have you tried debuging with any tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first error I found is:
you want `$_GET['link'])` in your php code, but only send a `click` parameter in JS. So you should change your JS code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","submit.php?link="+str,true);
```

try to run the php script without ajax to eventually find more errors.

Answer (score 2):

`It's going to google as it should, but it isn't inserting into the database.`

Yes, but make sure that the call to the php script actually works and that the script itself is free of errors, then look at the database.

Answer (score 1):

your using mysql_fetch_array($result2); for update use mysql_query($result2)

and its nor $_GET['link'] its $_GET['click']

Comment: he is actually updating with mysql_query(). your code would raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot the `;` mark here: `$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest use jquery & .post() method.
Syntax of this will be more readable by humans :)

```
// submit here ... 
$.post(
   "answer.php", 
   {
       start:  $("#ancor_id" )  . attr( "title" ) 

   }, 
   function(ret) {

      if (!ret.success )
      {
        alert(1);
      }
      else
      {
        alert( "Update Ok" );
      }
   }, 
   'json'
 );
```

where answer.php

```
<?
  header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
  $arr_json = array();
  $arr_json[ "success" ] = "true";
  echo json_encode( $arr_json );
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this please?